# Authenticating User in generic view?

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to extend a generic view to allow user authentication? I want my view to limit the number of returned results from the model if a user is not logged in.

```
class CustomGalleryDetailView(DetailView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return Gallery.objects.on_site().is_public()
        else:
            return Gallery.objects.on_site().is_public()[:5]
```

This returns NameError global name 'request' is not defined.

The reason I want to extend the generic view is that here I am simply overriding a single of many views used by a 3rd party app in my program, and I want to maintain some consistency with the rest of the views which mainly rely on generic views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just change it to `self.request.user.is_authenticated()`, so your class will become:

```
class CustomGalleryDetailView(DetailView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return Gallery.objects.on_site().is_public()
        else:
            return Gallery.objects.on_site().is_public()[:5]
```